# Ferrers Diagram Partition

Tags: combinatorics, integer-partitions

Show that any number of partitions of 2r + k into r + k parts is the same for any k using ferrers diagram.

Already tried to do by checking transpose etc. but cannot come up with a solution.

Comment: Look at the top (bottom) row of the diagram, depending on whether you are english or (sane).

Answer (score 0):

Let's illustrate this situation for the case $r=3$.  Initially $k=0$.  Then the total is $2r+k=6$ and we seek the partitions with exactly $r+k=3$ nonzero parts.  We disvover that there are three of them:

$6=4+1+1$

$6=3+2+1$

$6=2+2+2$

We translate these into Ferrers diagrams:

$4+1+1$

° ° ° °

°

°

$3+2+1$

° ° °

° °

°

$2+2+2$

° °

° °

° °

Now increment $k$ to $1$.  This increases the total to $7$ and the number of required terms to $4$.  Again there are three partitions satisfying these conditions:

$7=4+1+1+1$

$7=3+2+1+1$

$7=2+2+2+1$

To get a total as small as $7$ with as many as four nonzero parts, we need all the partitions to have a $1$ at the end.  We see this in the Ferrers diagrams:

$4+1+1+1$

° ° ° °

°

°

°

$3+2+1+1$

° ° °

° °

°

°

$2+2+2+1$

° °

° °

° °

°

Compare the two sets of diagrams:  the $k=1$ diagrams are just the $k=0$ diagram with one more single-unit row attached to the bottom.

What happens in general is that each $(r,k)$ diagram, for a total of $2r+k$ with $r+k$ nonzero parts, matches a diagram for $(r,0)$ plus each of $k$ additional units in a separate, additional row.